# International Mathematical Olympiad 2018 - Problem 1

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

> Let $\Gamma$ be the circumcircle of an acute-angled triangle $ABC$.  Points $D$ and $E$ lie on segments $AB$ and $AC$, respectively, such that $AD = AE$. The perpendicular bisectors of $BD$ and $CE$ intersect the minor arcs $AB$ and $AC$ of $\Gamma$ at points $F$ and $G$, respectively.  Prove that the lines $DE$ and $FG$ are parallel (or are the same line).

Comment: Is this an on-going contest ?

Comment: @Peter. The IMO has finished, as far as I know.

Comment: It finished on 10th - http://www.imo2018.org/#programme

Comment: IMO is such a big deal that one can expect to find solutions online. I did a quick search and found, among other things, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYSE9xn0l28) in a couple of seconds. I haven't watched it, so I can't vouch for correctness, but there are bound to be other materials out there. AoPS probably has a couple of pages on the problem as well, I'd wager.

Comment: I don't see why IMO problems can't be posted here.  There may be new solutions, and we should invite them.

Comment: @Batominovski Having originated from some particular contest doesn't grant PSQs any special status... And applying the "what if everyone did that" test to the situation seems to make it clear that it would not be desirable to have every country's contents problems appearing in this format. And who wants to validate which ones are actually from ordained contests?   So, exempting a question for the reason you suggest is impractical.

Comment: @rschwieb  High leveled contest problems are not easy and nontrivial enough, and they are interesting in their own right.  The argument "what if everyone did that" is irrelevant, because it will never happen.  Not everybody here is interested in advanced problems.  In fact, most questions that show up on each day are quite tame.  So, your argument is not quite practical.  (Except for on-going contests, of course, then I would agree that such posts should be locked down immediately.)

Comment: @Batominovski So to summarize: "interesting PSQs should get special treatment,"  "that would never happen." I disagree with the first claim and think the second one is a cop-out/wishful, but I suppose now we just leave it to others to decide for themselves.

Comment: @rschwieb  Yes, difficult problems should get special treatment.  They are harder to solve.  There are few to no textbooks that can help.  Problems are not created equal.  And difficult problems deter most people, so they are fewer people to be interested in them, let alone ask such questions.

Comment: @Batominovski I won't deny that interesting, difficult questions sometimes earn amnesty. But I really doubt this question is an example of that. I'm pretty sure in an overwhelming number of cases interesting difficult questions are not posted as PSQs.

Comment: @rschwieb Why?  You think this problem is easy?  It's probably the easiest of IMO2018, but it's not easy compared to most questions being asked on this site.  I can sympathize with the OP, who might have gotten stuck without ideas.

Comment: @Batominovski Easy? Permit me to not view the world as all black-and-white, and suffice it to say that the combined difficulty/interest level does not warrant an exception, IMO.  As always, with *even a tiny bit* of efforts on the poster's part, I would be willing to overlook all that.  I just have a hard time making excuses for posts that are 100% statement and 0% indicated effort.

Comment: @rschwieb  Maybe the OP should have written something about the effort.  However, we have different criteria.  I have a few check points in my criteria, and if one of them is positive, then I don't vote to close the question.   Difficulty is one of my check points.  After all, if the effort is simply junk and it's not a "check my proof" question, it is a waste of my time to read.  Nonetheless, to each his own.

Comment: @Batominovski Well, your process isn't anything special. What you wrote describes my process exactly except for the difficulty checkbox.  I might use such a checkbox if it weren't hopelessly subjective.

Comment: @rschwieb  There is nothing wrong with a subjective criterion.  The upvote/downvote system is very subjective.

Comment: @Batominovski I know how we use subjectivity and that it is inescapable in this line of work. Hence the qualifier *hopelessly* subjective. There are subjective measures, and then there are the hopelessly subjective ones, where one man's trash and another man's treasure are the same. At that point, it's unclear what the use of the criterion is. But I think that two people can usefully have subjective measures that differ by a constant, so to speak.

Comment: @rschwieb  I disagree that difficulty is hopelessly subjective.  The situation where an easy problem to one person is a very difficult problem to another happens often, but there are problems that can be seen almost immediately that they stand out in terms of difficulty, even by experienced mathematicians.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of $\Gamma$.  The perpendicular bisectors of the sides $AB$ and $AC$ meet the minor arcs $AB$ and $AC$ at $P$ and $Q$, respectively.  Suppose that the perpendicular bisectors of the line segments $BD$ and $CF$ intersect at $M$.

Note that $DE$ is perpendicular to the (internal) angular bisector $\ell$ of $\angle BAC$.  As $$\angle OPQ=\angle OQP=\frac{1}{2}\angle BAC\,,$$ it follows immediately that $\ell \perp PQ$.  This means $DE\parallel PQ$.

The distance $d_1$ between the parallel lines $OP$ and $MF$ equals $\frac{1}{2} AD$; likewise, the distance $d_2$ between the parallel lines $OQ$ and $MG$ is $\frac{1}{2} AE$.  Because $AD=AE$, we conclude $d_1=d_2$.

Now, rotate the line $OP$ about the point $O$ until this line coincides with the line $OQ$ in such a way that the image of the line $MF$ under this rotation is exactly the line $MG$ (this is possible because $d_1=d_2$).    Let $P'$ and $F'$ be the images of $P$ and $F$, respectively, under this rotation.  Therefore, $P'QGF'$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with parallel opposite sides $P'Q$ and $F'G$.  Thus, $PF=P'F'=QG$, so $PFGQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with two opposite sides $PF$ and $QG$ having equal length.  This means $PQ \parallel FG$, and we can then conclude that $DE\parallel FG$, as required.

[image]